# Threejs remap UV after CSG subtract

Tags: three.js, uv-mapping

I was able to subtract a mesh fron my main mesh. However the texture is not well mapped in the engraved part.

[image]

The texture inside the engraved part is quite small in comparison of my main mesh.

Is there a way to redo the UV Mapping, or any other solution to solve that ?

Comment: I don’t think there’s a way to correct that, since it depends on the CSG implementation that you’re using. This level of customization might need to be handled in 3D editing software, ur by modifying the CSG source code to remap UVs the way you want.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.
I used this library https://github.com/manthrax/THREE-CSGMesh
Let's try another implementation to see if I reproduce